# add elements to Java Array

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say we defined an array with 20 elements. is there any way we can add some objects to the array, without any specific order of course and not just once like `String[] t= {"one", "two", ..., "twenty"}` ?

```
String[] t = new String[20];
//I know this won't work
//but something like this:
//t = {"one", "two", "three"}
//and later, add some more
//t = {"four"} ...
```

Comment: Can you use `ArrayList`?

Comment: yes.. you could do array[5]="five", array[1]="one";

Comment: @TheLostMind yes, but it is not easy at least without a for loop ...

Comment: @user3580294 actually it is a really good idea, but I just wanted to make sure it is not possible to do this with a simple array

Comment: @Aaron It *is* possible (if your array doesn't change), but it'd just be a pain to do, since you'd essentially be writing your own `ArrayList`.

Comment: @user3580294: Well, almost possible. You still need the layer of abstraction to be able to transparently switch to another backing array (if the array needs to grow).

Comment: @Thilo Good point. Minor edit to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: ordering is an added advantage in array which you get without a hit on efficiency.. What is the problem if the array contains data as you enter it?. I would like to understand why you specifically need to do make it unordered.

Comment: @TheLostMind it is useful sometimes, but not in every case. for instance if you just want to store some Strings and then print them back, making orders doesn't make any sense

Comment: indeed.. But ordering data without any cost (barring the flexibility that arraylist provides) isn't exactly a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to initialize the elements in an `Array`,

```
String[] t = new String[20];
t[0] = "zero";
t[1] = "one";
```

You can also use [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy from one to another (if that's what you mean). Here concatenate Array(s) `a` and `b` to a new Array `c`.

```
String[] a = {"Hello"};
String[] b = {"World"};
String[] c = new String[a.length+b.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Output is

```
[Hello, World]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the size of the array, but you can assign elements at specific positions.

```
t[3] = "four";
```

Re-ordering and remembering where the array is supposed to end may or may not become cumbersome.

For more flexible "arrays", people like to use `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign values like this

```
t[10]  = "ten";
t[11]  = "eleven";
```

It is better to use ArrayList so there is no need of initializing the size first and it is dynamic too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not exactly how java arrays work. To instantiate and initialize an array use the syntax...

```
String[] t = new String[20];
t[0] = "One";
t[1] = "Two";
```

or,

```
String[] t = {"One", "Two"};
```

If you want more control over the array the I'd recommend using an `ArrayList` object instead where you can add, remove, change, sort the items in the array. For example,

```
ArrayList t = new ArrayList();
t.add("One");
t.add("Two");
t.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is a good option for ArrayList supports dynamic arrays that can grow as needed.
With arrays you can add elements by specifying the specific position you want to add 
like adding in position 4 we can do something like `array[3] = "four"`
but for more control arraylist is recommended

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Array should be used in below way only

```
String[] t = new String[20];
t[0] = "One";
t[1] = "Two";
...
t[19] = "Twenty";
```

You can try using arrayList: You need not even specify how many elements are expected while initializing.

```
ArrayList t = new ArrayList();
t.add("One");
t.add("Two");
...
t.add("Twenty");
```